# Why despite "drush" being installed via `composer global install` during image build, I cannot find the tool from within a running PHP script?

Tags: php, docker, composer-php, drush

I am developing a PHP web application inside of a Docker container. Using `volumes:` inside of my `docker-compose.yml` file, I have specified a local directory so that any files generated are dumped and persist after the container is destroyed.

```
volumes:
  - ./docroot:/var/www/html
```

Inside my `Dockerfile`, I `RUN` a command that installs a command line management tool:

```
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer && \
    ln -s /root/.composer/vendor/bin/drush /usr/local/bin/drush

RUN composer global require drush/drush:8.3.3 && \
    composer global update
```

When the container comes up, I can use `docker-compose exec -it <container> bash` to get inside the container, and everything works fine. `drush` is in my path, and I can use it globally throughout the container to manage the app.

Now here is the strange part. Part of my application is that I have to run that command from a PHP script inside the container to help automatically manage some of the build process.

Using php, I run `exec('drush dbupdate', $output, $retval);` $retval returns a exit status of 127, or command not found and $output is empty. If I switch up the exec to use the full path I get an exit status 126.

If I go back into the container, I can run that command just fine. Note all other cli commands work as expected with exec (`ls`, `whoami,` etc but `which drush` returns exist status 1)

What am I missing? Why can I use it with no problems manually, but PHP `exec()` can't find it? `passthru()`, `shell_exec()`, and others have the same behavior.

Comment: Have you tried `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/drush`? Maybe some permissions or different users (you login as root, but php runs from different user)

Comment: ah, we're getting somewhere. whoami shows the user www-data, but I thought how I had it installed from above, it could be used by all users.

Comment: Yup, but it's not. Refer to the answer below on why it is. :)

Answer (score 3):

`composer global install` will not install the command "globally" for all users, but "globally" as in "for all projects".

Generally, these packages are installed in the home directory for the user executing the command (e.g. `~/.composer`), and if they are available in your path is because `~/.composer/vendor/bin` is added to the session path.

But when you run `composer global require` (while building the image) or when you "log in" to the running container (using `exec [...] bash`) the user involved is `root`. But when your PHP script runs, it's being executed by another user (presumably `www-data`). And for **that** user, `~/.composer` does not contain anything.

Maybe do not install `drush` using composer, but rather [download the PHAR file directly or something like that](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/212274/21767) while you are building the image, and put it in `/usr/local/bin`.

If you are using Drupal >= 8, the recommended way of installing Drush is not as a "global" dependency, but as "project" dependency, so that the appropriate drush version is installed. This comes straight from [the docs](https://docs.drush.org/en/9.x/install/):

> It is recommended that Drupal 8 sites be built using Composer, with Drush listed as a dependency. That project already includes Drush in its `composer.json`. If your Composer project doesn't yet depend on Drush, run `composer require drush/drush` to add it. After this step, you may call Drush via `vendor/bin/drush`

Comment: curious to know more why the ln -s ... /usr/local/bin/drush isn't working as expected. I'm indeed a fan of dl'ing the .phar file, but Drupal is SO composer dependent these days I was hesitant to go down that route.  If I look at the permissions on the file they are owned by root:root 777.  How does what I wrote not achieve the same as mv drush.phar /usr/local/bin/drush?

Comment: I don't know if the composer installation gets you a self-contained phar archive you can move around. And the recommended way of installing drush is via composer, but not globally but locally to the project (so dependencies match). And if you want to use the same call path in all projects, use something like "drush-ops/drush-launcher" for that.